# How to override input[type=checkbox] css rule?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

My checkmark inherit this rule:

```
input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}
```

I override like this:

```
<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="flexCheckDefault" style="display:block;">
```

but it has no effect. Do you know why? I am using Bootstrap around it.

Comment: The css is working for me. Can you remove the `form-check-input` class and check what happens?

Comment: Doesn't have anything to do with the `display` property, that one gets applied fine from your inline style. `.form-check-input` applies `position: absolute; margin-top: .3rem; margin-left: -1.25rem;`

Comment: Hi, yes, removing `form-check-input` worked.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap is applying some position properties in the checkbox that's why it will not be displayed you can add parent div like the below code.